# Perform SVN operations through a ruby script on windows/osx

Tags: ruby, svn

I am a newbie and need to perform some basic SVN operations (like get info of the repository, add, commit, update etc) through a ruby script, on both windows/osx.

I searched the forum and internet, only to find partial and confusing answers related to SWIG ruby-subversion bindings etc, but none of them was well documented or simple enough to use [Also, most of these questions and answers are pretty old].

I am assuming that a simpler way to perform SVN operations through a ruby script should exist by now. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Also, is it worth the hassle to install SWIG bindings, understand 'svn/core' library and use it with a gem (like svn_wc) OR better to simply call svn command line commands from ruby? Is there a massive difference in performance for these approaches?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use SVN command line tools from Ruby.
Say you are in a sandbox and you have a script 'svn-get_uuid'.
It could look like this:

```
$ cat svn-get_uuid
#!/usr/bin/ruby
uuid = `svn info`.lines.grep /^UUID/
uuid =  uuid[0].chomp.sub /^.*: (.+)/, '\1'
print "{#{uuid}}\n"

$ ./svn-get_uuid
{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

May be you can do it faster using the svn-bindings, but working this way is OK for my daily work.

Comment: Well, that's what am doing currently - Calling the shell commands from the ruby script and grepping what I need. But there has to be a better and simpler way to do this. Am amazed that there is no stable/simple gem to do svn operations from within ruby :(

Comment: And your answer doesn't really help me . The only part related to SVN is calling the "svn info" command using backticks.